# how can I rewrite this line?

Tags: python, pygame

In my code I have the following line:

```
something = next((s for s in something if s.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())), None)
```

My question is, how can I rewrite this sentence spreaded over a few lines, so it will make my code more clear ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review.

Comment: How did you end up writing that in the first place? Do you not understand what it's doing?

Answer (score 2):

```
def next_something(something):
    for s in something:
        if s.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            return s
    return None

something = next_something(something)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could start by naming your variables more descriptively, and perhaps using an intermediate variable.

Even though I do it, too, I find it unreadable when a variable on the right-hand side has the same name as the variable on the left-hand side.

```
filtered_something = (s 
                      for s in something
                      if s.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_post())
first_something = next(filtered_something, None)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is pep8 compatible

```
something = next((
    s for s in somethin
    if s.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())),
    None)
```